# How should I store a long list of IDs in redis?

Tags: redis

I want to store a list of IDs (>100,000 of them) in redis.

So the list might look like: `332 99 91 78 10 98989 18221`

I'll also need to be able to check to see if multiple IDs exist within this list as well.

e.g. I'd need to be able to check at once whether 99 and 332 and 41 exists on the list.

How would I go about storing this type of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Hash in which each field is an id and the value is the empty string, e.g.

```
HMSET ids 332 "" 99 "" 91"" 78 "" 10 98989 "" 18221 ""
```

To perform the membership check:

```
HMGET ids 99 332 41
```

The reply will have an empty string for each existing value, and a null for the non-existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `SET` to store these ids. Although the `SISMEMBER` command can only check whether a single member exists, you can write a lua script to check the existence of multiple keys in one call.

```
-- multi-sismember.lua
for i, v in ipairs(ARGV) do
    if (redis.call('sismember', KEYS[1], v) == 0) then return false end
end
return true
```

Run it as `redis-cli --eval multi-sismember.lua key , 99 332 41`.